# I've created an infinite loop and I don't know why

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
namespace ChooseYourOwnAdventure
       {
         class Program
          {
           static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               /* THE MYSTERIOUS NOISE */

               // Start by asking for the user's name:
               Console.Write("What is your name?: ");
               string name = Console.ReadLine();
               Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! Welcome to our story.");
               Console.WriteLine("It begins on a cold rainy night. You're sitting in 
               your room and hear a noise coming from down the hall. Do you go 
               investigate?");
               Console.WriteLine("Type YES or NO");
               string noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine();
               string answer = noiseChoice.ToUpper();
               if(answer == "NO")
                {
                 Console.WriteLine("Not much of an adventure if we don't leave our 
                 room. THE END");
                 return;
                }
               else if (answer == "YES")
                {
                 Console.WriteLine("You walk into the hallway and see a light coming 
                 from under a door down the hall. You walk towards it. Do you open it 
                 or knock?");
                }
               else
                {
                 Console.WriteLine("Command not recognized");
                 while((answer != "YES") || (answer != "NO"))
                  {
                   Console.WriteLine("Type YES or NO");
                  }
                }
                 Console.WriteLine("Type OPEN or KNOCK");
                 string doorChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                 string answer2 = doorChoice.ToUpper();
```

I'm doing an exercise in Codecademy. I was creating my own adventure story before I did this so I thought this would be great practice to do anything that came to mind. I decided to do some error handling checks in case a user puts in some information which is where the else code block came from. I figured that if I used the while statement for any current and future errors the user introduces I could use the `Console.WriteLine` method to put the question forth until they type the specified values. Instead, the while I've created seems to have made an infinite loop within the compiler of "Type YES or NO". Can someone help me understand where I went wrong?

Comment: You are not changing the answer in the while loop. and your condition is wrong, it's must be && not ||

Comment: You have a `while` loop which continues when the answer is not "YES" or "NO". However, there is no way fror the value to change within the loop, so it loops forever.

Answer (score 2):

Every string is either not equal to "YES" or not equal to "NO" (e.g., if the input is "YES", it will not be equal to "NO", so the loop will continue). Instead of `||` (the logical "or" operator), you should use `&&` (the logical "and" operator):

```cs
while((answer != "YES") && (answer != "NO"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type YES or NO");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to remember how the computer thinks and not myself. I guess understanding the computer better will just allow me to think more logically as my comparisons were already flawed. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not re-assigning the `answer` variable in the `while()` loop you have made. @Mureinik is correct with why the loop is always active, but if they enter an input other than `YES` or `NO` then it will be infinite again. Try adding something like this:

```
while((answer != YES) && (answer != NO))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Type YES or NO");
     noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine();
     answer = noiseChoice.ToUpper();
}
```

Because you were never updating the `answer` variable the `while()` loop's statement was always true, hence the infinite loop.